# Paypal Payload for Payment Rest API 2

Tags: magento2, api, paypal, rest-api

Can anyone help me for payload of paypal standard we are trying two api's nothing works for us. We tried multiple payloads already but no success in order placement.

1. POST `/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/payment-information`
2. Selected method